# Python: TypeError while Train-Test splitting of data-frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
          date  datedelta
0   2012-03-30  0
1   2012-03-30  0
2   2012-03-31  1
3   2012-04-19  19
4   2012-04-20  1
... ... ...
240 2019-11-08  11
241 2019-11-14  6
242 2019-11-14  0
243 2019-11-24  1
244 2019-12-07  13

245 rows × 2 columns
```

I want to split it into train and test dataframes and this is what i did.

```
tr_start,tr_end = '2012-03-30','2016-01-28'
te_start,te_end = '2017-01-29','2019-12-07'
tra = x['date'][tr_start:tr_end].dropna()
tes = x['date'][te_start:te_end].dropna()
```

I cannot comprehend what I'm doing wrong. I'm getting this error after restarting the kernel in jupyter today and I'm positive there were no errors when I first wrote the code !! :@ please help me out here.

```
 TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.range.RangeIndex'> with these indexers [2012-03-30] of <class 'str'>
```

Getting this error on the third line.

Comment: try changing the str to date time format

Comment: Does this helps? ->https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28518944/cant-index-by-timestamp-in-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 1):

I think you need `DatetimeIndex` first and then select:

```
x = x.set_index('Date')

tr_start,tr_end = '2012-03-30','2016-01-28'
te_start,te_end = '2017-01-29','2019-12-07'
tra = x[tr_start:tr_end].dropna()
tes = x[te_start:te_end].dropna()
```

Or:

```
tra = x.loc[tr_start:tr_end].dropna()
tes = x.loc[te_start:te_end].dropna()
```

Comment: can I ask what was I doing wrong? Man, I swear It was running alright earlier.

Comment: @DevarshiGoswami - Sure, if use seelcting by datetimes `[tr_start:tr_end]` it always working with DatetimeIndex, not with column like you want use `x['date'][tr_start:tr_end]`

Comment: Thanks!  Also I tried  using somemodel.predict(te_start,te_end) I get the error KeyError: 'The `start` argument could not be matched to a location related to the index of the data.'

Comment: @DevarshiGoswami - It seems data related problem, can you check [this](https://discuss.analyticsvidhya.com/t/time-series-analysis/67474/15) ?

Comment: @DevarshiGoswami - Also you can check if both dataset has datetimeindex.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
df = df.set_index('date')
df = df.sort_values('date')
# # Slice the Data
tr_start,tr_end = '2012-03-30','2016-01-28'
te_start,te_end = '2017-01-29','2019-12-07'
tra = df[df['date'].between(tr_start,tr_end)].dropna()
tes = df[df['date'].between(te_start,te_end)].dropna()
```